# Kotlin smart cast not working for LinearLayout.LayoutParams

Tags: android, kotlin

I have implemented a function that I used to pass to anko`s applyRecursively.

Inside this function, I would like to add a marginEnd is the view is inside an LinearLayout, so I wrote the following code:

```
when(view.layoutParams) {
    is LinearLayout.LayoutParams -> {
        view.layoutParams.marginEnd = view.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.min_spacing)
    }
}
```

And I receive the error that the view.layoutParams is a mutable property that could have been changed. So I had to force the cast:

```
when(view.layoutParams) {
    is LinearLayout.LayoutParams -> {
        (view.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams).marginEnd = view.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.min_spacing)
    }
}
```

Looking here at stackoverflow I saw that Kotlin don't smart cast in variables that can be nullable, but the view.layoutParams is not nullable, so why the smart cast can't infer the type?

Comment: Uhm, because it's mutable, as the error message says? Nullability has nothing to do with smart casts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Smart cast won't work in this case, because the type of the variable you did the type check on could have changed since that check passed successfully (for example, by a different thread), and if it did, you'd get a runtime exception when you attempt to cast it.

The solution is either to do the cast manually as you did, or to introduce a temporary `val` to your function, which smart cast will work on, since we know its type won't change:

```
val params = view.layoutParams
when(params) {
    is LinearLayout.LayoutParams -> {
        params.marginEnd = view.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.min_spacing)
    }
}
```

**Edit:** As an additional note, you could also introduce this variable by using `let`:

```
view.layoutParams.let { params ->
    when(params) {
        is LinearLayout.LayoutParams -> {
            params.marginEnd = view.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.min_spacing)
        }
    }
}
```